# 403 Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]

Tags: apt, updates

When I entered sudo apt update,
It showed the following err.

```
~$ sudo apt update

    Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu focal InRelease
 
    Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
                  
    Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu focal InRelease 

    Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/avidemux/ubuntu focal InRelease 

    Err:3 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu focal-getdeb InRelease 403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]                   

    Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease  

    Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease

    Hit:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease

    Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease

    Reading package lists... Done

    E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/focal-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]

    E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu focal-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.

    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see this show you error because this page not found
http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/focal-getdeb/InRelease
you type sudo apt autoremove then then update again then tell me what show u

Comment: Does this help you? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2416369